# Error in converting an array to 2D matrix in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, data-structures

I have the problem regarding the output of this algorithm. *For example:* for input `chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 3)` it should return `[[ 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, '']]` but instead it returns `[[7, 8, 6], [7, 8, 6], [7, 8, 6]]`.

However, when `m_list` is defined under the loop `for r in range(rows):`, it returns correct value.

I can't figure out why it returns wrong value if `m_list` is defined outside the loop `for r in range(rows):`. What could be the reason ?

```
# --- Directions
# Given an array and chunk size, divide the array into many subarrays
# where each subarray is of length size
# --- Examples
# chunk([1, 2, 3, 4], 2) --> [[ 1, 2], [3, 4]]
# chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2) --> [[ 1, 2], [3, 4], [5, '']]
# chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3) --> [[ 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, '', '']]

import math

def chunk (array, size):
    rows = 0
    l = len(array)

    if l % size == 0:
        rows = l/size
    else:
        rows = int(math.floor(l/size) + 1)


    m_list = ['' for e in range(size)]

    m_matrix = [['' for g in range(size)] for w in range(rows)]

    i = 0

    for r in range(rows):
        for u in range(size):
            if i == l:
                break
            else: 
                m_list[u] = array[i]
                i += 1

        m_matrix[r] = m_list

    return m_matrix




length = int(raw_input('how many elements you want in the array?: '))

m_inputArray = ['' for q in range(length)]
print 'Debug0:--> ' + str(m_inputArray)
for z in range(length):
    p = int(raw_input('Enter the value at index %i: ' %(z)))    
    m_inputArray[z] = p

m_inputSize = int(raw_input('Enter the size: '))


result = chunk(m_inputArray, m_inputSize)
print result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code. Firstly every loop of `u` the start value of `m_list` is the previous list (so the first time it is `['','','']` but the second time it is `[1,2,3]`, and the third time it is `[4,5,6]`. Which means that since the third time only one value is left in the array, only the first value in the `m_list` gets redefined, resulting in an m_list of `[7,5,6]`.

Secondly, by saying: `m_matrix[u] = m_list` you are creating a *reference* to m_list, you are not copying `m_list` into `m_matrix`. This means that once `m_list` changes, so do the values in `m_matrix`. Which means in the end you will have defined `m_matrix` to be `[m_list,m_list,m_list]`, resulting in your results of `[[7,5,6],[7,5,6],[7,5,6]]`. A solution for this would be to make slice of `m_list`, like this: `m_matrix = m_list[:]`.

This is how I would do the whole thing:

```
def chunk(inputarray,size):

    array = inputarray[:]
    m_matrix = []


    while len(array) > 0:
        if len(array[:size]) < size:
            array.extend(['' for j in range(size-len(array[:size]))])
        m_matrix.append(array[:size])
        del array[:size]


    return m_matrix
```

If you don't need the original array anymore you can also remove the `array = inputarray[:]` line of code. Also, probably not the fastest/best way of doing this, but I just wanted to provide something quick. This was done in *python 2.7*, so if you're using another version you might have to alter some things.

Comment: I was missing the _reference_ part. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

seems a bit over complicated. this is what i came up with.
written for python 3 but does work in 2.

```
def pop_with_replace(array, index=0, blank=''):
    try:
        return array.pop(index)
    except IndexError:
        return blank
def chunk(array, size):
    out = []
    while array:
        t_list = []
        for i in range(size):
            t_list.append(pop_with_replace(array))
        out.append(t_list)
    return out
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(chunk(list(range(10)), 3))
```

there's some things we could change as well. like removing this method pop_with_replace for a ternary operator? i didn't put this in the first solution as they can be awkward to read if not used to them.

```
t_list.append(array.pop() if array else '')
```

looking at this we could roll it all up into a list comp. but we're starting to get hard to read.

```
While array:
    out.append([array.pop(0) if array else '' for x in range(size)]
```

but it does leave the final code looking nice and small.

```
def chunk(array, size):
    out = []
    while array:
        out.append([array.pop(0) if array else '' for x in range(size)])
    return out
```

Comment: Upvoted for the nice code. This code example is definitely more concise (and likely faster) than the example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this example there is only one m_list where you update values and final result is [m_list, m_list, m_list ... m_list].
If you define m_list in loop new list will be created in each loop pass.

You can assign directly to m_matrix[r][u] = array[i]

Note that you are with list of lists, not true matrix, and m_matrix[r] = m_list replaces list on r-th position with reference to m_list list.

Comment: I understand what are you saying but inside the inner _for_ loop everytime the values of m_list is updated and that updated m_list is being assigned to the m_matrix in the outer _for_ loop. So, don't you think by this way each index of m_matrix should have different m_list ?

Comment: No, because there is only one m_list.
Contents of m_list are different at moment of assignment to m_matrix, but memory location is same.
It might be more clear to you if you print m_matrix after each assignment to it.